# Download manager allowing to set the name of the output files - for Windows

Tags: download-manager

I need a download manager with graphical interface that can download batches of files, but I need it to be able to give certain names to the output files

for example I want to download a batch of 1000 links like these - https://www.wowhead.com/item=10001 - https://www.wowhead.com/item=10002 ..

And I need the files to be named 10001.htm 10002.htm

A better example might be this:

```
http://www.example.com/set1/20.jpg
http://www.example.com/set2/20.jpg
http://www.example.com/set3/20.jpg
http://www.example.com/set4/20.jpg
```

I need to set the names of the downloaded files like set1-20.jpg, set2-20.jpg, set3-20.jpg, set4-20.jpg

Another example is this:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044298/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072506/
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072562/
```

The downloaded files are named by default index.html, index.html.1 and index.html.2

All the download managers that I tried let you define a batch of URLs to be downloaded but they are not giving the user any control over the names of the file they are saved to.

Comment: Why not renaming the files after they have been downloaded?

Comment: Because after downloading 30 files named 20.jpg (each from a different image set), it is quite impossible to know to which set each image belongs. I get files named 20.jpg - 20 (1).jpg - 20 (2).jpg - etc. Some sets contain 10 images, some 20 images, other 30 images. How do I know from which set is the image "20 (5).jpg" ?

Comment: In that case downloading with directory structure would be the preferred way. That is more common especially to download tools that can mirror (partial) websites or subfolders of websites.